# How can I increase the 'special modifiers' section of my spell saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

I've been looking into ways to make it harder for monsters to make savings throws against me, and I noticed savings throws = 8 + your spellcasting ability modifier + any special modifiers. What is the "any special modifiers" and would I be able to take advantage of this?

Comment: What are the "couple of tricks" you have found?

Comment: Use these three simple tricks to make your spells more irresistible? Are we going to be seeing a buzzfeed article on this?

Comment: Please add the methods you've found, so that we don't have to repeat them in answers.

Comment: The best one I found was using contagion on the foe to give them disadvantage on the throw that I want them to make.

Answer (score 11):

The term "special modifiers" applies to any bonus to the DC of your spells that is not your spellcasting ability modifier or your proficiency bonus. Examples of this kind of bonus include the +2 bonus given by a Robe of the Archmagi or the +1, +2, or +3 bonus given by a Rod of the Pact Keeper.

Answer (score -3):

Seems like something they have avoided putting in this Edition so far.

I think your best bet is to have a range of spells that target different saves, or get a team mate to make the roll more difficult by adding disadvantage or subtracting from the roll.